# material button ripple z-index

Tags: jquery, css, z-index

I am creating a material button with a ripple effect. The ripple animation `.circle` looks like it's animating on top of it's parent `button` rather than underneath which is why the text is being covered. I am sure I have all the right syntax for using z-index. Here's the codepen link http://codepen.io/theMugician/pen/Bjadpj

```
button{
  z-index: 2;
  border: 3px solid #222;
  background: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;

  span{
    z-index: 2;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #222;
    position: relative;
    display: block; 
    user-select: none;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px;
    &:hover{cursor: pointer;}
  }
}

.circle{
  z-index: 1;
  display: block; 
  position: absolute;
  background: #5677fc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0);

  &.animate{
    z-index: 1;
    animation: effect 0.65s linear;}
}

@keyframes effect{
    100%{
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 1; 
    transform: scale(2.5);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding circle `span` to the `button span`. So circle `span` becomes a child of button's `span` and your z-indexes have no effect. Simply binding the click event to the `button` element itself fixes your issue:

```
$("button").click(function(e){
....
```

So button structure becomes this:

```
<button>
  <span>button</span>
  <span class="circle animate"></span>
</button>
```

and not this:

```
<button>
  <span>button
     <span class="circle animate"></span>
  </span>
</button>
```

**Updated Codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVdBPO**

Comment: Whoops. I made a silly mistake. Thanks for clearing that up.